# combing two models and only retrieving a.firstname, a.lastname, b.name and returning as list to populate in mvc view using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a `UserTbl` and a `CongregationTbl` and I am trying to combine them so that I can retrieve `a.FirstName`, `a.LastName` and `b.Name`.

UserTbl

```
| C_ID | FirstName | LastName |
+------+-----------+----------+
   1       Jim         Jones
   2      Frank        Snow
   1      Alice        Cruz
   2      Sarah        Lee
```

CongregationTbl

```
|  ID  |   Name    | 
+------+-----------+
   1      Bellham        
   2     Fortworth
```

What I want to do return a list and populate that into a view

Created view

```
    | Name   | FirstName | LastName |
    +--------+-----------+----------+
     Bellham     Jim         Jones
    Fortworth   Frank        Snow
     Bellham    Alice        Cruz
    Fortwroth   Sarah        Lee
```

This is what I have so far. It returns data, but I cannot get it into my list.

```
using (Model1 dc = new Model1())
{
    var id = (from b in dc.CongregationTbls select b);
    var list = from i in dc.UserTbl 
               where i.AccountConfirmed == false 
               select new 
                      { id.FirstOrDefault().Name, i.FirstName, i.LastName };

    MergeModel MyModel = new MergeModel();
    MyModel.PendingUsers = list.ToList();
    return View(myModel);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should model your merged one like this. It's like making a custom model that allocates the first two models's important fields:

```
public class MergedModel{
     public string congregation {get;set;}
     public string firstname {get;set;}
     public string lastname {get;set;}
}
```

Then fill that model with the two models' data like this.

```
var merged = from user1 in UserTbl
                     join congregation1 in CongregationTbl on user1.C_ID equals congregation1.ID
                     select new MergedModel {congregation = congregation1.Name, firstname = user1.FirstName, lastname = user1.LastName };
```

Also, please note that `var merged` will converted as `IEnumerable<MergedModel>`. If you use the list as a return to your view to be called as `@model IEnumerable<yourproject.Models.MergedModel>` then it should work. Otherwise you can just reassign `var merged` like so:

```
List<MergedModel> merged2 = merged.ToList();
```

This is how I do it. I hope it helps you in any way.

Comment: this worked! Created the 'MergedModel' and added that Model to my existing 'MergeModel' as a List and then returned it to my existing 'MergeModel'. Thanks!!